# Dash app Error: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I am attempting to create something simple with Dash by looking at the [uploads tutorial](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/upload) but with the exection of graphing the data versus creating a table.

Would anyone have any tips with the error I am running into with parsing the data?

```
  File "C:\Users\benb\Desktop\dash\hwsLineUpload.py", line 105, in update_graph
    df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
  File "C:\Users\benb\Desktop\dash\hwsLineUpload.py", line 52, in parse_contents
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This is the complete script, I know I have something wrong in the `def parse_contents(contents, filename):` function.. Any tips help, not a lot of wisdom here.

```
import base64
import datetime
import io
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



colors = {
    "graphBackground": "#F5F5F5",
    "background": "#ffffff",
    "text": "#000000"
}

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Not multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=False
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='myGraph')
])


def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)


    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))

            if df.empty:
                df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')

            if df.isnull().values.any():
                df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')


        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))

            if df.empty:
                df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')

            if df.isnull().values.any():
                df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return df


@app.callback(Output('myGraph', 'figure'),
            [
                Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
                Input('upload-data', 'filename')
            ])
def update_graph(contents, filename):
    fig = {
        'layout': go.Layout(
            plot_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"])
    }

    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
        fig['data'] = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='scatter', mode='lines+markers', size=1)


    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The file I am testing this with a csv file I have in [this git repo](https://github.com/bbartling/Heating-Plant-Analysis), boilerData.csv

Comment: that generally means there is no `,` in `contents` to split

Comment: I also tried saving the CSV file in Excel to an Excel workbook.xls, and I get the same exact error... Would you have any tips to try?

Comment: It's looks like you can't use `return df` here, you need to return `html.Div([
html.H5(filename),]` or something like that. For your goal (as I think, you want csv file) - you can look for insights in [this](https://docs.faculty.ai/user-guide/apps/examples/dash_file_upload_download.html) code snippet. It helps me download pictures after object recognition; so I hope this help you download your csv

Answer (score 0):

Parse_contents use a delimiter which is here by default , the coma
When splitting the content itself it can't be assigned to 2 variables because there is only one value to assign. Try again with content_string = parse_contents(x,y)

Comment: Could you give me a tip if I have updated my code correctly? `def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type = contents.split(',')
    content_string = parse_contents(x,y)

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)`

Comment: Sorry the formatting in the comment section didnt work very well. But with `content_string = parse_contents(x,y)` this refers to modifying the `parse_contents` function right? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already found the problem, but here is my answer for future reference:

The problem is that in case you set `multiple=False` in the `dcc.Upload`, its `contents` and `filename` are not lists, but single elements.

The following change to the method `update_graph` should work:

```py
def update_graph(contents, filename):
    fig = {
        'layout': go.Layout(
            plot_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"])
    }

    if contents:
        #contents = contents[0]  # Remove this line
        #filename = filename[0]  # Remove this line
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
        fig['data'] = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='scatter', mode='lines+markers', size=1)

    return fig
```